# Use Enum for property class in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I am new in C# and what I want to achieve is following.

I have an Action class with Type property which takes one of the following values, Button or Link:

```
public class Action
{
    public ActionType Type { get; set; }

}


public enum ActionType
{
    Button,
    Link
}
```

I am using WebAPI and for now I use following mocked list to check returned data

```
private static IList<Alert> alerts = new List<Alert>()
{
    new Alert()
    {
        Description = "You have cancelled your subscription",
        Actions = new Action[]
        {
            new Action()
            {
                Type = ActionType.Button
            }
        }

    }
};
```

When I test in the browser I get

```
"Actions": [

    {
        "Type": 0
    }

]
```

What I would like to achieve is return values "button" or "link" for the type property. I tried to do something like this where I define ActionType:

```
public enum ActionType
{
    Button = "button",
    Link   = "link"
}
```

but I get following error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'.

How can I fix the above error?

Comment: Use your returned enum, and use the .toString method on the returned enum.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: as a FYI if you don't define a value for a enum 0 is assumed for the first value. If you were to set it to ActionType.Link the value would be 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your own JSON serialization, for instance using Json.net, which has an attribute for that. Take a look at this:

```
class Example
{
  [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
  public ActionType ActionType { get; set; }
}

var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Example(), Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just define your enum as:

```
public enum ActionType
{
    Button,
    Link
}
```

And if you need it as a string use:

```
var myEnum = ActionType.Button;
var myEnumAsString = myEnum.ToString();
```

This is not exactly the most performant way to go. But it is the easiest.

Otherwise you can create a

```
public static class ActionType
{

    const string Button = "Button",
    const string Link = "Link"

}
```

But this is essentially an enum, but without the int base.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign only `integer` values to keys in the `enum`, say

```
  public enum ActionType {
    Button = 1,
    Link   = 2
  }
```

if you want to assign *string* (or *whatever*) to *enum* key you can implement an *extension method*:

```
 public static ActionTypeExtension {
   // Extension method: extends ActionType ("this" before ActionType)
   // returns string
   public static String ToReport(this ActionType value) {
     if (value == ActionType.Button)
       return "button";
     else
       return "link";
   } 
 }

....

  ActionType action = ActionType.Button;
  String result = action.ToReport(); // <- "button"
```

Answer (score 1):

Enum is a set of named constants whose underlying type is any integral type (int, byte, long etc). String is not integral type, so you cannot use it as enumeration values. You can change property type to `string`

```
public class Action
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

and use class with public string values instead of enum:

```
public class ActionType
{
    public static readonly string Button = "button";
    public static readonly string Link = "link";
}
```

**But** I would go with usage of enum and passing integer values. Enums are better to use if you have set of values, because string does not restrict what you can assign to property `Type` of action. I can assign "Foo" and that will be OK, because I can even don't know about `ActionType` class existence. With enumeration you will have much more safety - property have type of `ActionType` and unintentional assignment of wrong value is not possible. Also passing integers will use less traffic than passing string names of enum constants.

Comment: For strings you can use the const if it is going to be Readonly static

Comment: @RobertSnyder constants are in-lined in caller code, so usage of constants can have side effects if you define ActionType in separate assembly. Usually I try to avoid public constants

Comment: You can use `const`, but there is a difference - if you change the value of a `const`, anything that uses it must be recompiled - not true for a `static readonly`.